# How to detect if .h files contains functions that arent defined in .cpp file?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

Problem is simple... I manually write .h and .cpp files, so sometimes I'm worried that ill declare a function and because of typing error or something Ill either define a different function or Ill completely forgett about it. So is there a tool that would recursively go through all may source folders and detect if pairs (SOMETHING.cpp and SOMETHING.h) have mismatches... I know that sometimes it is desired(or at lest I remember hearing that being a trick of some sort) but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: A header can contain prototypes for functions defined in many different source files. In my opinion, the best way to find out problems is simply to build the application and see what errors you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you attempt to use the function, you'll get an error from the linker.  Since you're testing all of the functions you write (you are, I hope), you won't be able to link the tests if you've a typo in the function name in the sources.

Another thing that can help: put your functions in a namespace.  In the header, you'll write

```
namespace MyNamespace {
void myFunction(...)
}
```

In the source, you don't open the namespace, but specify it for each function:

```
void MyNamespace::myFunction(...) { ... }
```

If `myFunction` hasn't been previously declared in `MyNamespace`, the compiler will complain.

Comment: cool, tnx, and no I dont use testing, Im still a beginner, so I suck but I try to improve... I have played with gtest, it is nice tool...